# Can't purchase with faith in converted cities

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Once a city converts to my faith, I can't buy any Faith-based buildings, like Monasteries or Mosques... but I can purchase them fine in cities that don't follow my religion. Is this a bug, or intended game mechanics?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a bug to me, it is exactly inverse to how it should be.

Comment: Is it actually your own religion that has the beliefs that enable those buildings, or were they taken by the creator of some other religion that you're pushing out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A city can only build a building if the majority belief in the city has that building as one of its follower tenets.

Is it possible that your religion doesn't have that tenet, but the one you are pushing out does?

Comment: I didn't think of that. Good point there!